# How do you show a timer in objective-c as a label on screen?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

The game i'm slowly developing currently has a label that updates (counter++) every click. I no longer want the amount of clicks to be displayed in this label, but want a second timer from the first click that occurred. I have tried a bunch of different methods I researched online but I can't get any of them to work.

Comment: Have you tried to use NSTimer with 1 sec as time interval?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an instance of NSTimer

```
 @interface YourViewController(){
 NSTimer stopWatchTimer; 
 NSDate *startDateTime;
}
```

Then when your button is tapped just fire the timer and store startDate like so

```
 if(![stopWatchTimer isValid])
 {
   startDateTime = [NSDate date];
   stopWatchTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0/10.0 target:self selector:@selector(stopWatchReading) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
 }
```

Finally implement the stopWatchReading method

```
-(void)stopWatchReading
{
  NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
  NSTimeInterval timeInterval = [currentDate timeIntervalSinceDate:startDateTime];
  NSDate *timerDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:timeInterval];

  // create the date formatter
  NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
  [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];

  [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0.0]];
  NSString *timeStr = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:timerDate];

  //set the text to your label
  [self.myTimerLabel setText:timeStr];
}
```

Comment: This was so helpful! Thanks so much for the detailed response I really appreciate it. I did notice however this resets the timer at each touch which wasn't my intention, I probably worded the question poorly. I want the timer to start on first mouse click and keep counting (no matter how many mouse clicks occur after)

Comment: I have fixed to code in stopWatchReading method with if statement. Please accept my answer if it was helpful for you.

Comment: Also if it's not too much trouble (so I could experiment), how would i make this timer just keep counting up from 1 (and not reset a new minute at 60)? Never ending upward timer.

Comment: Also after adding the if statement, the whole timer no longer shows up. I will happily award you best answer thanks so far :)

Comment: Sorry. I put the if statement on a wrong place :) check the code again

Comment: Perfect! How about my question about not counting in minutes? Is it possible with this implementation?

Comment: you just want to get the total seconds since started is it?

Comment: yeah so everything as it currently is except at 60 seconds instead of increasing 1 minute and starting the seconds again, i just want it to keep counting 61...62...102 ect. No base 60 necessary

Comment: In that case just update your label with the following
yourLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",timeInterval];

Answer (score 0):

You could do it using an **NSTimer**. 
Please read the following link in which you'll find the basic of the class [NSTimer Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html).
You would need to schedule a method every one second, and then update your label.
If you were using **Cocos2D** for your game, you'd also use **scheduleSelector**. (More from this amazing engine here [Cocos2D Website](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/)).

Another option would be to find an already made component that provides the functionality you're trying to achieve. Here is one I've found for you in Cocoapods repository, but please check other options to see which of them fully match your needs. [**MZTimerLabel**](https://github.com/mineschan/MZTimerLabel)